# Get the latest record as per a DATETIME type from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello StackOverflow community,

I have 2 tables

```
products
=======
id
name

prices
======
id
product_id
price
date_added
```

The column 'date_added' is of DATETIME type.

My question is how can I select the products.name, prices.price, prices.date_added where the date_added is maximum.

The result set should contain 1 row per product with the price and the max date_added.

Please let me know if this is not understandable enough!

HERE IS A SET OF RECORDS

```
INSERT INTO `prices` (`id`, `product_id`, `price`, `date_added`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1.23, '2011-11-16 13:18:14'),
(2, 1, 1.25, '2011-11-17 13:18:24'),
(3, 2, 1.5, '2011-11-15 13:18:32'),
(4, 3, 1.89, '2011-11-15 13:18:41'),
(5, 4, 0.98, '2011-11-14 13:18:57'),
(6, 5, 1.87, '2011-11-17 13:19:29'),
(7, 5, 1.98, '2011-11-16 13:19:44'),
(8, 3, 1.87, '2011-11-13 13:19:52'),
(9, 2, 1.45, '2011-11-05 13:20:01'),
(10, 1, 2.34, '2011-11-16 13:20:10'),
(11, 4, 2.87, '2011-11-18 13:49:21'),
(12, 5, 1.64, '2011-11-19 13:49:33');

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Karamhtros'),
(2, 'Tralalas'),
(3, 'Giwrgos'),
(4, 'Sotiris'),
(5, 'Tassos');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT p.name, pr.price, pr.date_added
FROM products p INNER JOIN prices pr
  ON p.id = pr.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING pr.date_added = MAX(pr.date_added)
```

**EDITED after user comment:**
Try this one

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, pr.price, pr.date_added
FROM products p INNER JOIN prices pr
  ON p.id = pr.product_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT product_id, MAX(date_added) AS da 
            FROM prices GROUP BY product_id) pr2
  ON pr.product_id = pr2.product_id AND pr.date_added = pr2.da
```

Comment: `prices pr`, not `prices p` :)

Comment: I have no idea why it did not work... it returned only 2 results for a total of 5 products.

Would a dump help somehow? I have no idea how to explain further...

Comment: @Marco I added my records :) PS I added p.id to the select statement just to distinguish a bit better the results. It didn't actually change anything of course.

Comment: @Marco I tried it and the results are wrong. With your last query I do get a row for each product but the prices are not with the latest date. In fact 2 of them are and the other 3 are not...

Comment: @Marco it appears that this time the results are correct.
Thank you for your time! I'll go and accept it :)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.name, pr.price, pr.date_added  
FROM products p
INNER JOIN prices pr ON (pr.product_id = p.id)
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING pr.date_added = MAX(pr.date_added)
```

Comment: @Johan thanks for your answer, if you could contribute a bit more I'd be much obliged and grateful! Thanks again :)